# Vega-lite rolling averages within groups

Tags: julia, vega-lite

I have a table of data that summarizes prices vs. number of users. When I want to display the scatter plot overlaid with a moving average line I use the following Julia function:

```
function log_scatter(df::DataFrame; smooth=2, title="Price by Number of Users")
    sort(select(df, [:Price, :Users]), :Users) |> 
    @vlplot(width=640,height=512, title=title) +
    @vlplot(mark={:point, opacity=0.5}, x={field=:Users, scale={type="log"},title="Users"}, y={:Price,title="Price per User"}) +
    @vlplot(transform=[
        { groupby=[:Users], aggregate=[{ op=:mean, field=:Price, as="AvgPrice" }] },
        { frame=[-smooth,smooth], window=[{ field="AvgPrice", op=:mean, as="rolling" }] }
        ],
        mark={:line,size=2,color="red"}, x={:Users, title="Users"}, y={"rolling:q", title="Average"})
end
```

It produces a nice plot: [image]

Unfortunately when I want to do the same with grouping, I can't get the moving average to display

```
function log_scatter_and(df::DataFrame, other; smooth=2, title="Price by Number of Users")
    otherSym=Symbol(other)
    prices = price_and(df, other)
    sort(select(prices, [:Price, :Users, otherSym]), :Users) |> 
    @vlplot(width=640,height=512, title=title) +
    @vlplot(mark={:point, opacity=0.5}, color=otherSym, x={field=:Users, scale={type="log"},title="Users"}, y={:Price,title="Price per User"}) +
    @vlplot(transform=[
        { groupby=[:Users, otherSym], aggregate=[{ op=:mean, field=:Price, as="AvgPrice" }] },
        { frame=[-smooth,smooth], window=[{ field="AvgPrice", op=:mean, as="rolling" }] }
        ],
        mark={:line,size=2,color=otherSym}, x={:Users, title="Users"}, y={"rolling:q", title="Average"})
end
```

This is the output when I try to group by year
[image]

I want to have the rolling average lines show up as well as the scatter

Answer (score 2):

I'm not good at `VegaLite`, but I encounter `StatisticalGraphics` that I guess uses `vegalite`, thou. you need to add the main branch

```
using InMemoryDatasets
using StatisticalGraphics
using RollingFunctions

ds=Dataset(y=rand(1000), x=rand(1:200,1000),year=rand(2000:2010,1000))
sort!(ds, :x)
modify!(groupby(ds,:year), :y=>(x->runmean(x,2))=>:rolling)
sgplot(ds, [Line(x=:x,y=:rolling, group=:year), Scatter(x=:x,y=:y,group=:year)], nominal=:year, xaxis=Axis(type=:log))
```

Answer (score 1):

window transform has to have a groupby statement,

```
function log_scatter_and(df::DataFrame, other; smooth=2, title="Price by Number of Users")
    otherSym=Symbol(other)
    prices = price_and(df, other)
    sort(select(prices, [:Price, :Users, otherSym]), :Users) |> 
    @vlplot(width=640,height=512, title=title) +
    @vlplot(mark={:point, opacity=0.5}, color=otherSym, x={field=:Users, scale={type="log"},title="Users"}, y={:Price,title="Price per User"}) +
    @vlplot(transform=[
        { groupby=[:Users, otherSym], aggregate=[{ op=:mean, field=:Price, as="AvgPrice" }] },
        { groupby=[:Users, otherSym],frame=[-smooth,smooth], window=[{ field="AvgPrice", op=:mean, as="rolling" }] }
        ],
        mark={:line,size=2,color=otherSym}, x={:Users, title="Users"}, y={"rolling:q", title="Average"})
end
```